# Accessing Keycloak within a docker-compose network fails

Tags: docker-compose, keycloak

I use Keycloak for user management in an environment orchestrated by docker-compose.
An access token is generated by a javascript frontend client that is sent to the backend via the HTTP `Authorization` header.

When I try to get user information from a micro-service written in Python, I ran the following code:

```py
# Base URL: http://keycloak:8080 (Internal in Docker. Doesn't work)
url = 'http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo' 
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

Surprisingly, this resulted in `401 Unauthorized` error.

I finally discovered that if I change the URL to the external one (of the host machine), then everything works as expected:

```py
# Base URL: https://202.97.95.108:8443 (External. Works. Note: 202.97.95.108 was randomly generated)
url = 'https://202.97.95.108:8443/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

This returns `200 OK` and the user information as expected.

I seriously wonder why that is, and whether I can and should change something so that the internal docker hostname would work.

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:  
  backend-micro-service:
    build:
      network: host
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./backend-micro-service/Dockerfile
    expose:
      - "5080"
    networks:
      - intranet
    depends_on:
      - keycloak

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:15.0.1
    expose:
      - "8080"
    ports:
      - "8443:8443"
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
      - DB_VENDOR=POSTGRES
      - DB_ADDR=keycloak-db
      - DB_SCHEMA=public
      - DB_DATABASE=${KEYCLOAK_DB}
      - DB_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    depends_on:
      - keycloak-db
    networks:
      - intranet

  keycloak-db:
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - keycloak-database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    expose:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${KEYCLOAK_DB}
      - POSTGRES_USER
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    networks:
      - intranet
 
networks:
  intranet:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  keycloak-database:
```

Comment: Try to configure a fixed frontendUrl, either in the realm settings or via the [hostname provider](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#_hostname)

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the token issuer URL is being compared against the Keycloak server URL of the HTTP request upon token validation.

- The issuer URL for the token starts with `https://202.97.95.108` since it was generated by a client adapter (for JavaScript) that connects with Keycloak using the external address.
- The Keycloak server URL of the HTTP request starts with `http://keycloak`.

Possibly because of this mismatch, the token validation fails. However, I wasn't able so far to verify this explanation (setting the log level to `DEBUG` didn't provide additional information).

Comment: Did you able to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem as you, the solution for me was to set the **Frontend URL** field in the realm settings, in the "**General**" tab, in my case adding the address "**http://localhost:28080/auth**", which is exposed by the docker container where keycloak runs.

I hope I was helpful.